# how to inject headers in a `@context HttpServletRequest`?

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey-2.0

Let's say I have this code:

```
@ApplicationPath("...")
public class MyApp extends ResourceConfig {
    public SalesLayerApplication() {
        this.register(HeaderInjecterFilter.class);
        this.register(Test.class);
    }
}

@PreMatching
public class HeaderInjecterFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext crc) throws IOException {
        crc.getHeaders().add("foo", "bar");
    }
}

@Path("/test")
public class Test {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String dump(@Context final HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader("foo");
    }
}
```

I was expecting to call the rest entry point /test and to retrieve the string `bar`.

But all I see is null

If I use `@HeaderParam("foo")` I correctly retrieve the variable, but I need to access throug the `@Context HttpServletRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect that adding headers to the ContainerRequestContext would also add it to the HttpServletRequest? These are completely unrelated entities. Try injecting `HttpHeaders` or you can also inject the `ContainerRequestContext` directly.

Comment: are you saying that the headers of the context of the request are in a different container that the headers of the request? How does `@HeaderParam` works???

Comment: `@HeaderParam` is taken from the ContainerRequestContext, not the HttpServletRequest. The ContainerRequestContext is built from the HttpServletRequest, and then Jersey just uses the ContainerRequestContext for processing, not the HttpServletRequest